# MacPCのソフトウェアアップデートを行ってからUnityで作成したアプリが開かなくなった

Tags: macos, unity2d

ソフトウェアアップデートを行ってから以前起動出来ていたUnityで作成したアプリが開かなくなりました。
アプリアイコンをControlキーを押しながらクリックして、開いたメニューから「開く」を選択した場合でも開けませんでした。
警告文章には「提供元が不明のため～」の文言の表記はなく「アプリケーション"アプリタイトル"を開けません」としか表示されませんでした。
こちら別PCでは起動することを確認していますのでアプリの不具合で起動しないというわけではないと思います。
こちらどうすれば開くことが出来ますでしょうか。

起動しないPCの環境
macOS Catalina
バージョン10.15
MaxBook Air(13-inch, Early 2015)
プロセッサ 1.6GHz デュアルコアIntel Core i5
メモリ　8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
グラフィックス　Intel HD Graphics 6000 1536 MB

開発中のUnityバージョン
Unity 2018.3.13f1

Comment: 対象ソフトが違いますが、これら [macOS Catalina にしたら、Anaconda 使えなくなった場合の対処法](https://qiita.com/akinko/items/1909c8d0145d9ba530b9), [OSX Catalina でAnacondaをインストール](https://tako1192.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/10/12/OSX_Catalina_%E3%81%A7Anaconda%E3%82%92%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB) が類似の問題かもしれませんね。

Comment: 他にも色々と問題が多いようですね。[macOS Catalinaの不具合、アプリの動作不良、各種問題報告まとめ](https://gori.me/macosx/macoscatalina/121856), [macOS Catalinaにアップデートしたら動かなくなったアプリと対処法](https://tamoc.com/catalina-stuck-application/), [そのMac、更新して大丈夫？ ～「macOS Catalina」へ移行する前にチェックしたいポイント（10月9日追記）](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/serial/yajiuma/1211564.html), [macOS Catalina（10.15）がリリースされましたが、インストールはくれぐれも慎重に](https://dtptransit.design/mac/dont-install-catalina-yet.html), [新しいMacのOSは、ちょっと影響がデカイので注意【macOS 10.15 Catalina】](https://funq.jp/flick/article/517742/)

Comment: アプリをWebからダウンロードすると起動できませんでした。
USB経由でしたら起動出来たのでアプリではなくセキュリティの問題だと思うのですが、セキュリティを「すべてのアプリケーションを許可」にしても開くことは出来ませんでした。

Comment: macOSは経験無いですが、システムのエラーログとか何か発生したエラーの詳細を調べる手段とかは無いのでしょうか？あればそれを調べればよいのでは？

Comment: わたしもUnityのバージョンは違うのですがおそらく同じ問題にぶち当たっています。
MacOS 10.15 Catalinaにアップデートしたら、Unityを起動すると、Project選択までは開くのですが、Projectを選択し読み込むと、読み込むあたりで画面が真っ白になり、応答しなくなります。 macOS 10.13 High Sierraでは正常に動いていました。
かなり困っています・・・(エンジニアではないので・・・)。

Comment: @すけまめ さん。それはこの質問とは別現象のようです。使っているUnityがCatalinaで動作しない版数なのかも？ いったんアンインストール・再インストールを試すとか？ それでインストールが上手く行かないか、まだUnityが動作しないなら、OS版数を元に戻すか、Unity版数を上げるか、のどちらかではないでしょうか？ [Installing Unity on macOS Catalina](https://forum.unity.com/threads/installing-unity-on-macos-catalina.689089/), [OSX](https://forum.unity.com/forums/osx.95/)